Телеграм бот не сканирует всех пользователей чата
Хочу добавить в своего бота возможность активации в чате и чтобы бот сразу отсканировал всех участников внутри. В итоге код выдаёт ошибку и не активируется в чате. Подскажите, что сделать
ниже код и ошибка
user_data = {}

with open('languages.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    translations = json.load(file)["translations"]

async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    user_id = update.message.from_user.id
    if user_id not in user_data:
        user_data[user_id] = {
            'selected_artists': [],
            'language': 'ru'
        }
    await update.message.reply_text(get_translation(user_id, 'start'))

async def activate(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id

    
    user_status = await context.bot.get_chat_member(chat_id, update.message.from_user.id)
    if user_status.status not in ['administrator', 'creator']:
        await update.message.reply_text("Only administrators can use this command.")
        return

    
    chat_members = await context.bot.get_chat_members(chat_id)

    
    if 'chat_users' not in user_data:
        user_data['chat_users'] = {}
    for member in chat_members:
        user_data['chat_users'][member.user.id] = chat_id

    await update.message.reply_text("Bot has been activated for all users in this chat.")

Ошибка
No error handlers are registered, logging exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dmitri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\_application.py", line 1325, in process_update
    await coroutine
  File "C:\Users\Dmitri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\_handlers\basehandler.py", line 157, in handle_update
    return await self.callback(update, context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\Dmitri\Desktop\telegrambot\ChartMakerTop.py", line 44, in activate
    chat_members = await context.bot.get_chat_members(chat_id)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'ExtBot' object has no attribute 'get_chat_members'. Did you mean: 'get_chat_member'?


В ошибке же ясно написано - нет такого метода get_chat_members, читайте документация. Я не знаю, что вы используете для создания бота, но возможно поможет переустановить принудительно новую версию pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall <package>
